Ubuntu VM running on HyperV Windows 10 machine remote login will not stay toggled on
I have an Ubuntu VM running in HyperV on a Windows 10 machine. I'm trying to configure Ubuntu to allow remote logins so I can use Remote Desktop from my Windows host to login but the toggle that allows remote login in the Ubuntu settings won't stay on. I know I can use the built in HyperV viewer to run the VM and get into it from Windows but I'm specifically trying to log in using Remote Desktop
Here's the setup:
Host Machine:

Windows 10 Enterprise version 22H2
OS Build 19045.5131
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0
HyperV manager version 10.0.19041.1

VM:

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel 6.8.0-49-generic
Desktop Environment: Gnome 46.0
Shell: Bach 5.2.21
Window Manger: Mutter
Windows Manager Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
xrdp version 0.9.24

Here's a gif showing what it's doing:

I've looked and have not been able to find anything in the documentation that gives any additional steps needed to enable remote login nor have I found any posts anywhere that talks about this issue. I don't even know what other information to post to help troubleshoot this. If someone will please help me figure out what is going on I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!
